# Switching between firebase user pages

Tags: firebase, flutter

so i am a flutter beginner and i am developping a flutter application in which user should login then 'HomePageEtud' page should route him to different pages 
the problem is that i've tried this code but it didn't work 
any ideas could be helpful 
thanx

```
class HomePageEtud extends StatefulWidget {

  final FirebaseUser currentUser;

  HomePageEtud(this.currentUser);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
  callpage(int currentIndex) async {

switch (currentIndex) {
  //case 0 :  Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/Etud/Reminder');
  case 1 : return ForumPage();
  case 2 : return ReminderPage(currentUser);

  break;

default: SchedulePage(currentUser);
   }
  }

}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePageEtud> {

  final db = Firestore.instance;
  int _currentIndex=0;


FirebaseUser currentUser ;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(

        body: HomePageEtud(currentUser).callpage(_currentIndex),


    bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,

      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.school),title: new Text("schedule"),backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.people),title: new Text("Forum"),backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.calendar_today),title: new Text("Reminder"),backgroundColor: Colors.black),

      ],
      onTap: (value){
        _currentIndex = value;
        setState(() {


   }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you change the _currentIndex but you do it outside the `setState`.
you should change the `onTap` function to this:

```
onTap: (value) {
    this.setState(
        _currentIndex = value;
    );
}
```

and I think you forgot a break in your switch